# How to match on a longer word using MySQL Full Text Search?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have 2 tables : Company and category (category table has tags field, I wrote keywords for each category, I used comma(,) as delimiter)

When I search something, it will first search in the company table and then search the query in the tags field.

I wrote the query but I have a problem. When I search "emlak", everything is fine but if I search "emlakçı" it can't find anything. Do I have to enter "emlakçı" as a keyword in tags field or is it possible to solve this with an another way?

Here is my query :

```
SELECT
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS company.*,
    MATCH(company.c_title) AGAINST('SEARCH TEXT') as nameScore,
    MATCH(category.tags) AGAINST('SEARCH TEXT') as tagScore
FROM company LEFT JOIN category ON company.c_cat_id = category.c_id
WHERE MATCH(company.c_title) AGAINST('SEARCH TEXT')
OR MATCH(category.tags) AGAINST('SEARCH TEXT')
ORDER BY nameScore DESC
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, Murat. I retitled your question to put an emphasis on full-text search. You can rollback to your original title, but I felt this was clearer to your problem.

Comment: Why are you using a comma delimited field for tags instead of a tags table and a join table?  Comma delimited lists in a RDBMS are possible the worst anti-pattern there is.

Comment: Could this be a character set issue?  Do other words with accents such as `ç` have similar problems?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your original query

```
SELECT
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS company.*,
    MATCH(company.c_title) AGAINST('SEARCH TEXT') as nameScore,
    MATCH(category.tags) AGAINST('SEARCH TEXT') as tagScore
FROM company LEFT JOIN category ON company.c_cat_id = category.c_id
WHERE MATCH(company.c_title) AGAINST('SEARCH TEXT')
OR MATCH(category.tags) AGAINST('SEARCH TEXT')
ORDER BY nameScore DESC
```

You may want to try running the fulltext searching before doing the LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS company.*,
    company.nameScore,category.tagScore
FROM
    (SELECT *,WHERE MATCH(c_title) AGAINST('SEARCH TEXT' IN BOOLEAN MODE) nameScore
    FROM company WHERE MATCH(c_title) AGAINST('SEARCH TEXT' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) company
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT *,MATCH(tags) AGAINST('SEARCH TEXT' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as tagScore
    FROM category WHERE MATCH(tags) AGAINST ('SEARCH TEXT' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) category
    ON company.c_cat_id = category.c_id
ORDER BY nameScore DESC;
```

As for the search string `emlakçı`, try using a wildcard character. In other words,

```
MATCH(tags) AGAINST ('emlak*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This may pick up more occurrences but should get emlak and similar strings

## **UPDATE 2012-07-30 18:01 EDT**

I don't know your table structure. Assuming `name` is a field in category, try this:

```
SELECT
    company.name,category.name,COUNT(1) CategoryCount
FROM
    (SELECT *,WHERE MATCH(c_title) AGAINST('SEARCH TEXT' IN BOOLEAN MODE) nameScore
    FROM company WHERE MATCH(c_title) AGAINST('SEARCH TEXT' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) company
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT *,MATCH(tags) AGAINST('SEARCH TEXT' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as tagScore
    FROM category WHERE MATCH(tags) AGAINST ('SEARCH TEXT' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) category
    ON company.c_cat_id = category.c_id
GROUP BY company.name,category.name;
```

Comment: Thx for the answer but i get an error. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near "WHERE MATCH(c_title) AGAINST('SEARCH TEXT' IN BOOLEAN MORE) nameScore FROM company"

Comment: I corrected the syntax. I had `BOOLEAN MORE` which should have been `BOOLEAN MODE`

Comment: in addition to this, how can i count how many rows are found in each category

Comment: If i use group by , then it returns only one row

Comment: Then, the search falls under one category. Is that so ???

Comment: when i search a company , it gets the result it's ok. For example. A Company belongs to category id 5 and B company belongs to category id 10 and so on... So i want to count how many rows found in each category so that i can show that
Real estate(5)
Restaurant(2)

Comment: Now, I am confused. Are you talking about using the same query to get counts per company per category ???

Comment: yes, it it possible with this query ?